# Identify and update SQL record from datagrid

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2012

I have a simple app in C# Visual Studio 2012 that contains a Data Grid showing the records from an SQL table.
I have added the text boxes and combo boxes to add new records, that works just fine.

What i am trying to do is update an existing record directly in the data grid. I have the button with the update query but i have one problem. How do i identify the record in the grid that was modified?

Lests say the grid shows

```
ID   Name     Age  Gender
---- -------- ---- --------
1    Steven   21   M
2    Dan      34   M
```

This data is shown using

```
SELECT * FROM table.
```

I go into the grid and i modify the Age for the second record from 43 to 36.
To save it i need to run an update query, but how can i tell that the ID that was modified was 2? Is there any way i can do this? Or any other way?

EDIT:

It works like this to update the datagrid:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("user id=testuser12;" +
                                      "password=Reporting11#;Data Source=SERVER;" +
                                   // "Trusted_Connection=yes;" +
                                      "Initial Catalog=Partner_database; " +
                                      "connection timeout=30");
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select * from [dbo].[Test_table]", con)
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
DataSet set = new DataSet("cucu");
sda.Fill(set,"cucu");
dataGridView1.DataSource = set;
dataGridView1.DataMember = "cucu";
```

I am now testing to see how to do do the DataSet.AcceptChanges(); part, because if i use a button how do i call the dataset? because the dataset is in another part of the code.

EDIT2: I tried to write this into an answer but my answer was deleted with no explanation so i am forced to do another edit here.

I have tried what you said but it does not seem to work. I have the Data grid showing the data but when i modify an existing report and click SAVE i get an error:"Update requires a valid UpdateCommand when passed DataRow collection with modified rows."

the save button code is:

```
private void test_tableBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Validate();
    this.test_tableBindingSource.EndEdit();
    this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.partner_databaseDataSet);

}
```

And the fillby function is:

```
 private void fillByToolStripButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        this.test_tableTableAdapter.FillBy(this.partner_databaseDataSet.Test_table, valueToolStripTextBox.Text);
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }

}
```

On save the error shows on the following line:

```
this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.partner_databaseDataSet);
```

Do i need to modify what the save button is doing? There is no ".AcceptChanges" .

Comment: Did you tried this DataGridView.CellValueChanged Event?

Comment: No i didn't. Will search about this and try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this declaring public variables :

```
    private string variabila;
    private int varsta;
    private DataSet set = new DataSet("cucu");
    private SqlDataAdapter sda;
    private SqlCommandBuilder cmdBuilder;
```

And using the `SQLCommandBuilder` for the update:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SERVER;" +
                                          "Initial Catalog=Partner_database;" +
                                          "Integrated Security=True");
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select * from [dbo].[Test_table]", con);

    sda = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
    sda.AcceptChangesDuringFill = true;
    sda.AcceptChangesDuringUpdate = true;
    set.Clear(); //just to make sure i have a clear set
    cmdBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(sda); //use the command builder to create the commands
    sda.Fill(set_date,"cucu1");
    dataGridView1.DataSource = set_date;
    dataGridView1.DataMember = "cucu1";
}
```

And to save the updated records into the database:

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      sda.Update(set.Tables["cucu"]);
}
```

The `Update` command is not working without the Command Builder.

Answer (score 3):

I left the other answer for short reference. Please follow this "tutorial" on a sample project before so you can get the full picture of what it is and how to use it. It might sound a bit basic in some places but it is good for other people using SO.

### 1) Create a new WinFom application

On Visual Studio, click `FILE -> New -> Project`. Select `Windows Forms Application`, give it a name or leave the default and hit `OK`.

### 2) Add a Database connection

Click on the `VIEW -> Server Explorer` menu or simply use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>,<kbd>L</kbd> keyboard combination. (That is holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and hitting <kbd>W</kbd>then <kbd>L</kbd>)

On the opened panel, click the `Connect to Database` button.

[image: Connect to Database]

Fill in the required fields, test the connection and click `OK`

[image: Create connection]

### 3) Create a Data Source

Click on the `VIEW -> Other Windows -> Data Sources` menu or simply use the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> keyboard combination.

On the opened panel, click the `Add New Data Source` button.

[image: Add New Data Source]

Select `Database` in the first screen, `Dataset` in the second and hit `Next`. Select the data connection you just created from the drop down and click `Next` again twice.

In the database objects selection screen, choose the table(s) you want to include in your dataset and click `Finish`.

[image: Database objects]

### 4) Add a DataGrid to the Form

In the `Data Sources` panel, click on one of the objects you previously selected and select `DataGridView`

[image: DataGridView]

Next, drag and Drop the object name into the form. Some controls (including a data grid) will be generated. the Data Grid will be set up with the required connections, bindings and data sources.

[image: Generated Controls]

### 5) Browse the code

Try to go through the generated code and controls properties to get a better understanding of the solution. Notice the following generated lines of code in the Form:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'testDataSet.Language' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
  this.languageTableAdapter.Fill(this.testDataSet.Language);
}

private void languageBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  this.Validate();
  this.languageBindingSource.EndEdit();
  this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.testDataSet);

}
```

A `TableAdapter` was generated for the object and was filled with data from the `testDataSet` while loading the form.

The `Save` button (little floppy disk icon) is calling `tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.testDataSet)` which will implicitly call the `DataSet.AcceptChanges()`.

Please note that you can narrow the scoop of the Data Set by changing the selection queries (by clicking `Add Query` in the previous screen).

### 6) Creating parametrized queries - EDIT

You can use parameters in customs queries for a given dataset. You can use the following query in your case:

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE (Id = @Value)
```

ADO.NET will generate a new `FillBy()` method which you can use instead of the regular `Fill()` in the `Form_Load` method. The generated method will have a signature similar to:

```
public virtual int FillBy(TestDataSet.TableDataTable dataTable, int Value)
```

Please note that the number of input parameter will be extended by the number of query parameters you have. The type will match the type of the field in the target database (hete `int` for an Id)

`@Value` is valid for SQL Server. If you are using another DBMS use `?` instead

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE (Id = ?)
```

Comment: thank you for this. But the data that i am showing in the data grid is filtered. If you look in my code the SELECT query is simple but i am selecting * from table where column equals variable from textbox. Im not sure if i am explaining this correctly. So i am showing all records from SQL table that have the name = "Dan". in those record i want to change some info in the data grid, and save. I am not sure i can use variable from text boxes to filter the data shown in the example you gave above. Hope i am clear on explaining this.

Comment: Please check the edit, did that answer your question?

Comment: trying this. thank you so much for your time. As soon as i get it to work i will mark the reply :)

Comment: do i need to create a refresh button to have the grid updated when i change the parameters? for example i show the records with name = Dan and then i change the name to Julie in the text box.

Comment: Yes, you need a way how to execute the `FillBy()` method again, most probably a button

Comment: Apparently my answer was deleted. Since i cannot add code into the comment, how can i do this? @Bohemian, please give me a sollution on how to show code into comment. Thank you.

Comment: try to edit your question or use the normal formatting options

Answer (score 0):

You should probably think of using a `DataSet` if you are not already using one. You can define a DataSet as data source in your DataGrid and defines the queries you need to run to display the required data.

After you made changes, it is a matter of calling `DataSet.AcceptChanges()` which will take care of all the hassle you are asking about.

Here is some useful documentation on how to use a DataSet:

- [DataSet Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (look to Example at the end)
- [TableAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7zt3ycf2.aspx) (usually used in conjunction with DataSet)

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to use a dataset to get my data in the grid but it shows nothing. I cannot add the code in here, how do i do this? Do i reply to my own question?

Comment: I have edited my initial question. I have added what is under EDIT:.

Comment: I will get back to you with a sample, I am writing it now